# How to pass a component's function to a component inside of navigationoptions

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

so I've been dealing with this problems for days now and have been googling a lot and trying to implement a solution. Most solutions suggest using 
`this.props.navigation.setParams({function: this.function.bind(this))` inside of `componentDidMount` and then doing something like this in navigationOptions ->

```
static navigationOptions = {
header:  ({navigation})  => 
   <Button onPress = { () => navigation.state.params.function}/> }
```

This works for buttons with onPress but this method doesn't seem to work when it's just a 'props' to a Custom Component.

This is my code

```
static navigationOptions = {
header:  ({navigation})  => 
   <CustomCar refreshCar = {navigation.state.params.refreshCarSearch}
   />

transitionConfig: () => ({
  transitionSpec: {
    duration: 0,
    timing: Animated.timing,
    easing: Easing.step0,
  },
}),
};

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state =  {
      Car: ' '
    }
    this.refreshCarSearch = this.refreshCarSearch.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
this.props.navigation.setParams({ refreshCarSearch: this.refreshCarSearch });
               }

refreshCarSearch(e){
    this.setState({
        Car: e
        });
                }
```

I always get navigation.state.params.refreshCarSearch is undefined. I've tried a lot of variations of this method but to no avail. This method only works if I replace the component with a button with onPress, but I need to pass this function over. Basically, I need to have my CustomCar component (which must reside at the top of the screen, so in navigationOptions) pass a value back to this Component so refreshCarSearch can happen. The only way I've read how to do this is with Redux or this case where the parent component passes the refreshCarSearch function to the 'child' component. The component existing in navigationOptions makes it much more difficult, is this possible?

Comment: Can you try passing the function as screenProps to the component so you can access screenProps directly inside your navigationOptions.

Comment: @AshwinMothilal Could you explain about that a bit more? Im not sure about the syntax. My stack navigator is located on a different page. Do you mean to pass it to the screen component there as props?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a parent component, you are sending a function called refreshCarSearch on props which doesn't work in your case.

```
<ParentComponent refreshCarSearch={this.refreshCarSearch}/>
```

So, you have to send refreshCarSearch like this

```
<ParentComponent screenProps={{refreshCarSearch:this.refreshCarSearch}}/>
```

In navigationOptions of your child component you can access it like this

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation, screenProps}) {
header:  ()  => 
   <Button onPress = { () => screenProps && screenProps.refreshCarSearch}/> 
}
```

One more thing to add here is I'm not sure whether params on header returns navigation object but the one above returns the navigation and screenProps object(navigationOptions static method params).

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want this customer Car component at the top of the screen you should call this component at the top in render function and then you will get your refreshCarSarch `this.props.navigation.state.params.refreshCarSearch`
eg:

```
render(){
 return (
   <CustomCar refreshCar = {()=>this.props.navigation.state.params.refreshCarSearch()}
   />
)
}
```

Comment: I would like it to be inside of the navigation bar though. Otherwise its right under.